# Как перенаправить вывод звука на микрофон в Android?

Tags: android, linux, звукозапись

Короче говоря, цель такая: нужно воспроизвести музыку с телефона, а вывод направить в микрофон - т е, чтобы при записи с диктофона, при звонках, отправке голосового сообщения, вместо (или параллельно) окружающего звука воспроизводится мой аудиофайл. ОС - Android 10, но также в наличии Termux и Kali Nethunter, могу использовать что-либо оттуда. [просто это chroot, так что я не уверен, сработают ли у меня решения под штатные Linux дистрибутивы].

Comment: нет таких функций в андроиде

Comment: @eri, можно пересобрать с такой возможностью.

Comment: что именно пересобрать? либы, бинарники, драйвера, ядро?

Comment: Я не специалист по Android, я не знаю, где именно нет поддержки. В самом худшем случае надо пересобирать ядро, добавлять библиотеки, переписывать какой-то родной HAL, чтобы он работал с этой функциональностью. Проект на $1m (не шутка, грубая оценка затрат).